# How can I put data in array in real time?

Tags: java, arrays, audio, streaming, real-time

(If you are unfamiliar with sound programming, see "EDITED")

I'm writing Media Art program, and I want to do following thing.

There are one `SourceDataLine` running,
and for example, every 10 ms,
I send byte array of length 1764 by `sourceDataLine.write()` method.
(44100 Hz,16bit stereo audio data,  441 samples * 2 bytes(16 bit) * 2 channels = 1764)

If there exists audio data to play already,
this is quite easy to implement.
That is, pick up 1764 from audio byte array and send to `sourceDataLine` 100 times per second.

From here, my question.
I want to play sound when mouse is clicked.
So, I can't know sound data to play beforehand.
To do this, I must know timing of click,
and from timing information, I write sound data in appropriate position
of byte array.
How can I do this?

One method I can think of is
when sound is started, I store  `System.nanoTime()` to `long` variable,
and when clicked, I measure the position of sound.
but it seems uncool.

I will not use MIDI for this purpose,
because I want to synthesize sound.

Thank you.

EDITED
for those not familiar with Java audio API.

I want to record timing of click in particular sample rate,
and output that record data real time.

EDITED2
Checking whether clicked or not in every sample is maybe impossible,
because of two reasons.
1. interval is very short. (about 23 microseconds in 44100 Hz case)
2. accuracy (of timing) of resulting data will fluctuate.

Comment: The `SourceDataLine` deals with the timing, all you have to do is call the `write` method with the data you want to output.

Comment: @greg-449 That is not answer for my question. I want to make audio data from unpredictable event and play that in real time.

Comment: How does the mouse click change what sound you will play? Playing one set sound on a click is do able with some kind of listener on the mouse click. Im not sure how one can vary a click to produce different sounds though.

Comment: @BenKnoble For example, a

Comment: Ok so you want to always play an a when a user clicks a mouse? Then you just need to already have the sound data you want to play and listen for the mouse click event. It sounded earlier like you wanted to play different notes based on how a mouse was clicked, which seems impossible to me.

Comment: @BenKnoble Sorry ,previous comment is mistake. For example, sine tone's frequency is sweeping up, and when clicked, direction is changed i.e. sweeping down.  And moreover, to merely play some sound on click, if there are so many events, it is not good because playing sound clip requires sound device object for each events.